# Is there a Tool for see files created with binary serialization?

Tags: .net, reflection, serialization

I've working without problems serializating object graphs to and from files. Everything was fine until today: A dictionary, created in a constructor and NEVER deleted, was lost (null referece) just after deserialization from file, for the first time in more than a year doing the same without troubles.

So, is there a Software Tool to look into binary serialization content showing a human/developer-readable version (a la Reflector) of what is stored?

AKA: How to analyze (easy, no binary to IL translation. That would take months) binary serialized content?

Thanks!

Comment: "human/developer" : I love the fact that you make a distinction between developers and humans ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about any tools, but remember that some deserializers do not call the constructors.  Check out the OnDeserializedAttribute to have code run after deserialization.

Comment: Can you share a code repro so we can better understand what you're seeing?

Comment: A code repro does not apply in this case. I want to see (in an understandable way) the content of .NET binary serialized data.

Answer (score 1):

Try Notepad++

I has the bin/Hex feature - and it can use UTF-8

This is nice because you can see the actual sequences for UTF-8 - also BOM bytes

I know this is not binary - but it does show the raw content - bytewise that is ...